# Configure tomato on cisco e2500

Tags: networking

I'm trying to configure tomato on my e2500. I'm able to install the firmware and connect to the network and even ping (from the admin console) outside websites but when I try to access the internet via browser I get an error. I'm pretty sure my routing table was configured correctly. I heard sometimes depending on your ISP you may have issues with this. I have a small local provider (Advanced Cable) but running a trace route it seems like they buy service from comcast.

I'm also sure I've used the right version of tomato.

Comment: "I get an error" is not a very good problem description. Can you ping from the computer? Can you traceroute out past the router? Does DNS work?

Comment: Ping from computer yes, traceroute yes. How can I tell if the DNS is working properly? Usually in the browser I don't get passed "sending request" it just times out.

Comment: You can do something like `ping www.google.com` and see if it returns a DNS error or starts pinging.

Comment: it does. sends and receives packets. 0% loss.

Comment: If DNS works and ping works, it sounds like the issue is with the browser itself. Maybe it's configured to use a proxy or something like that.

Comment: but why would it work when not using tomato? i had to reinstall the cisco firmware to get my regular access back.